# .get mootools method not working in joomla 1.5

Tags: mootools, joomla1.5

i have a problem in joomla 1.5.18. i'm trying to get text from an element using for instance

```
var divContent = $$('#myDiv').get('text');
```

but each time i get the error, in chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Object #`<HTMLDivElement>` has no method 'get'; in firefox: divContent.get is not a function. why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

even following samples in mootools i get the same.

i know how to do it for each object in the collection. i got doing $$('.') and using the "each" method:

```
$$('p.classname').each(function (el){
      el.addEvent('click', function() {
          var txt = el.get('text');
          ...
      });
});
```

and obviously i add the function onto domready. i don't use jquery 'cause mootools & jquery stops the events each one... -i tried once & what i needed didn't work- and i wish to use all joomla resources including mootools.

checking the version in mootools.js it says 1.13 (?)

Answer (score 0):

not sure which version of mootools comes in joomla 1.5.18, it may be 1.2.5. if so, `.get` should work but not as you expect it to.

You are probably a jquery user, used to `$("#myid")` and find that the only way to get similar results with the # in there in mootools is via `document.getElements`, aka, `$$`.

the problem is, to get a single item by id in mootools, you actually do `document.id("mydiv")` or even `$("mydiv")`. `$$("#mydiv")` will actually return a COLLECTION of elements with a single member, so `[obj]`, so the real element is `$$("#mydiv")[0]`.

if you apply a `.get` method to a COLLECTION, the getter normally iterates via a .each through all members and performs the get individually. it will return a new array member for each member of the collection - i.e. `["innertext"];` - though there should be a method for the collection, make sure that the element is there, it's in `domready` / `onload` and it's a unique id.

Still, I'd swap to using the `$("mydiv").get("text")`, it ought to be fine. This is all all too common assumption of jquery users that don't read the manual, in my experience. It results in bad and un-performant code due to all the `.each` iterations mootools has to silently do to work with the collection for you. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can also (and should) upgrade your Joomla to the latest version (security fixes, etc) and I believe it was about version 1.5.20 they included a newer version of mootools right out of the box (also there is a plugin for mootools upgrade you can enable).  I believe the version included out of 1.5.20 is like 1.2.5 or something...

That may help!